# Best Way to Link Two PC's to One Router?

Tags: networking, router, internet, home-networking, desktop-computer

I wanted to linkup two PC's to the one Router. They are in adjacent rooms next to each other. One of the PC's is used for Home Working. This meant that the person using the PC in the other room could not be Online at the same time as the Home Worker PC user. The PC that's used for Home Working needs the only Ethernet Cable. So the other PC in the other room can't be Online as there is only 1 cable. The PC's DO NOT have a Wireless Card. What would be the best way to connect them? Could i use a long Ethernet Cable? I have a PlusNet Full Fibre Router. Thanks

P.S. I bought a Brand New TP-Link AV1000 Powerline Starter Kit and it broke on the same day! I am returning it to Argos.

Comment: Yes, you could use long ethernet cables.  Best way?  Buy cheap wireless adapters for both boxes.  Even cheapie USB wireless adapters work great.  Does your router not have WIFI?  Also.. TP-Link is often garbage.  I have had good results from them too.. but usually garbage.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "both PCs could not be online at the same time". What's preventing that currently?

Comment: Do you mean a Dongle and why would I need 2?

Comment: Please clarify your question.  It appears that more than one of us are confused by it.

Comment: The PC that's used for Home Working needs the only Ethernet Cable. So the other PC in the other room can't be Online as there is only 1 cable.

Comment: This is easy to do.   Ethernet connection Second router (other room)  LAN to LAN on main router. Static IP on network. Turn OFF DHCP on second router.

Comment: I should add that the 2 PC's do not need to share files.

Comment: Just buy a second Ethernet cable? You don't need a second router or anything.

Comment: Add an Ethernet switch to the end of the long cable. Then cable each PC to the switch.

Comment: @user1686 I believe this post is a troll. This statement, “So the other PC in the other room can't be Online as there is only 1 cable.” makes no sense.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: "Makes no sense" does not imply "this is a troll post"...

Comment: @user1686 Look at [their own “answer”](https://superuser.com/a/1729333/167207) and let me know what you think now.

Answer (score 0):

Plusnet routers (from what I see online) are pretty standard 4 port SOHO devices.   This means that the easiest way to solve this problem is to have a cable running from each computer into one of the 4 LAN ports on the router.    You probably don't need to do anything else - so just by a long enough network cable and plug it in to the second computer!

I know you mentioned that you only need 1 computer online at a time, but you would land up having both computers online this way - its the easiest and fastest way to do it.  (If you specifically only want 1 computer online at a time that is an entirely different question)

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to just get a long Ethernet cable. Thanks all :)